# ngrx/data add new property to existing collection

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, reducers, angular-ngrx-data

I'm currently using **NgRx/data** and I have 2 collections: **Courses** and **Lessons**.

I found something in their documentation to overwrite **EntityCollectionReducer**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AdditionalEntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory {
  constructor(private entityDefinitionService: EntityDefinitionService) {}
  create<T>(entityName: string): EntityCollectionReducerMethodMap<T> {
    const definition = this.entityDefinitionService.getDefinition<T>(
      entityName
    );
    const methodsClass = new AdditionalEntityCollectionReducerMethods(
      entityName,
      definition
    );

    return methodsClass.methods;
  }
}
```

and in **AdditionalEntityCollectionReducerMethods**, I overwrote some methods to add the new property:

```
export class AdditionalEntityCollectionReducerMethods<T> extends EntityCollectionReducerMethods<T> {
  constructor(
    public entityName: string,
    public definition: EntityDefinition<T>
  ) {
    super(entityName, definition);
  }

  protected saveAddOne(collection: EntityCollection<T>, action: EntityAction<T>): EntityCollection<T> {
    const ec = super.saveAddOne(collection, action);
    (ec as any).saving = true;

    return ec;
  }

  protected saveAddOneSuccess(collection: EntityCollection<T>, action: EntityAction<T>): EntityCollection<T> {
    const ec = super.saveAddOneSuccess(collection, action);
    (ec as any).saving = false;

    return ec;
  }

  protected saveAddOneError(collection: EntityCollection<T>, action: EntityAction<EntityActionDataServiceError>): EntityCollection<T> {
    const ec = super.saveAddOneError(collection, action);
    (ec as any).saving = false;

    return ec;
  }
}
```

Also in **course.module.ts** I specified this property as **additionalCollectionState** in **entityMedatata**:

```
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  Course: {
    ...
    additionalCollectionState: {
      saving: false,
    },
  }
  ...
};
```

The AdditionalEntityCollectionReducerMethods was registered in **app.module.ts** as provider:

```
{
   provide: EntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,
   useClass: AdditionalEntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory,
},
```

So, in this way, I'm adding a new property called **saving** in the **Courses** collection.
But my problem is that if I'm using the **saveAddOne** method in other modules, the **saving** property will be added also here and I don't want this.

I think this is happening because I've registered the **AdditionalEntityCollectionReducerMethodsFactory** in **app.module**, but I tried to register this in **course.module** and to debug, but the breakpoint is not hit there (only in **app.module**). I also have to mention that the **course.module** is lazyloaded.

Is there a possibility to add a new property in only one specific collection?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do this

For in-depth: https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-metadata

```
export const appEntityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  Hero: {
    /* optional settings */
    filterFn: nameFilter,
    sortComparer: sortByName
  },
  Villain: {
    villainSelectId, // necessary if key is not `id`
 
    /* optional settings */
    entityName: 'Villain', // optional because same as map key
    filterFn: nameAndSayingFilter,
    entityDispatcherOptions: { optimisticAdd: true, optimisticUpdate: true }
  }
};
```

Register metadata:

```
EntityDataModule.forRoot({
  ...
  entityMetadata: appEntityMetadata,
  ...
})
```